# elasticdump between two servers using different versions of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've two servers with different versions of elasticsearch running on them. I am not able to run elasticdump to transfer all of my data from one to another.
Source es version: 2.3.3
Destination version: 1.7.5

I've verified both the servers have es instance running on them but the query:

**elasticdump --input=http://src_ip:9200/some_index5 --output=http://dest_ip:9200/some_index5 --type=analyzer**

stucks here:

Thu, 15 Sep 2016 14:42:39 GMT | starting dump

Thu, 15 Sep 2016 14:42:39 GMT got 1 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 0)

---

**UPDATE**

The next day I tried this, it worked! Nothing was changed upto my knowledge except that when I last tried, I'd just started elasticsearch on the destination IP. Does anyone have any idea that why would it not work in the previous case? Does elastic search take sometime to get things started?

Comment: Try `--type=data` if you want to transfer the data

Comment: The index I want to transfer completely is not currently there on the destination. So, was going to run --type=mapping and --type=data after dumping the analyzer.

Comment: Also, if you do --type=data it creates mapping dynamically, right? By that, mappings might get misconfigured.

Comment: First do `--type=analyzer`, then `--type=mappings` and then `--type=data`

Comment: yes. I did do that but then this got stuck yesterday. I am thinking the reason it got stuck was because I'd just started elasticsearch as service then may be it took time to get things started.